# CalDAV and CardDAV sync apps?

Tags: sync, contacts, calendars, carddav

Are there any third party apps to sync Windows Phone 8 with a CalDAV/CardDAV calendar and contact server?

From searching online, I have found vague suggestions that there are developers out there working on it and that there even should be one for WP7. But I have not found anything in the App Marketplace.

Comment: There are no third party apps for WP7 that are capable of creating new contacts, as this was not permitted. WP8 does open up this possibility though, so it may be the case that such an application is out there/under development.

Answer (score 2):

GContacts does CARDDAV.  http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/gcontacts/76e2d69f-e469-4084-b565-d4a6343aee31 . Encourage the dev to do calendar too.