# Transfering contacts from an iPhone

Tags: 8.0, sync, contacts, carddav

Until I can get my hands on [a CardDAV client application](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/1289/721), I need to transfer my contacts from iOS or OS X to my Lumia 920.

How can I do this **without** uploading my contacts to Outlook/Hotmail/Gmail or anything like that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Nokia contacts transfer app (iPhone 4 and higher) or your SIM card.

> If you only want to transfer your contacts, use the [Transfer my Data](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=dc08943b-7b3d-4ee5-aa3c-30f1a826af02)
>   app on your new phone. If you don’t have this app, you can download it
>   from Store. If you have previously had a micro-SIM or micro-RUIM card,
>   you can also copy your contacts from your card to your new phone. For
>   more information on how to copy contacts to your SIM or RUIM card, see
>   the user guide of your phone.

Or you will have to cave and sync them to an email account.

Source [Nokia support](http://www.nokia.com/us-en/support/troubleshooting/?action=singleFAQ&caseid=FA140263_en_US).